# Cross compile with a Makefile uses wrong includes

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, gcw0

I am trying to compile the audiofile library for the MIPS processor

here is my configure command:

```
./configure  --build i686-pc-linux-gnu --host mipsel-gcw0-linux-uclibc --prefix=/opt/gcw0-toolchain -target mipsel-gcw0-linux-uclibc
```

then when I run Make it includes my computers headers sometimes e.g.:

```
In file included from /opt/gcw0-toolchain/usr/mipsel-gcw0-linux-uclibc/sysroot/usr/include/features.h:416:0,
                 from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:25,
                 from ./../AudioFormat.h:26,
                 from Module.h:25,
                 from ModuleState.h:25,
                 from ModuleState.cpp:23:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:115:56: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 __MATHCALL (modf,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__iptr)) __nonnull ((2));
                                                        ^
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:115:56: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 __MATHCALL (modf,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__iptr)) __nonnull ((2));
                                                        ^
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:115:56: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 __MATHCALL (modf,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__iptr)) __nonnull ((2));
                                                        ^
make[3]: *** [ModuleState.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/audiofile-0.3.6/libaudiofile/modules'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/audiofile-0.3.6/libaudiofile'
```

I have tried using all different folders in my configure command but the same error happens every time

Answer (score 1):

`--build` option of `configure` used to indicate the building environment, because you are doing a cross-compiling, so you should use something like

```
./configure  --build mipsel-gcw0-linux-uclibc --host mipsel-gcw0-linux-uclibc ...
```

By the way, that `--target` option is unnecessary in your case, because your are not building compilers, linkers, or something like them.